# Why is Blockly not generating code for custom blocks?

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

While generating code for custom blocks in blockly, i am getting error

```
Error: Language "Python" does not know how to generate  code for block type "import_block".
```

when logging in console.

Following is the code for block creation

```
Blockly.Blocks['import_block'] = {
      init: function() {
        this.appendDummyInput()
            .appendField("import")
            .appendField(new Blockly.FieldTextInput("default"), "import_name");   
        this.setOutput(true, null);
        this.setColour(230);
     this.setTooltip("");
     this.setHelpUrl("");
      }
    };
```

The code generation code is

```
    let code = (Blockly as any).Python.workspaceToCode(Blockly.mainWorkspace);
    console.log(code);
```

The block is visible in UI.
Also the code gets generated for default blocks present in blockly but shows error for custom blocks.

Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't show the code you wrote for actually transforming your block into code I can only assume that it's missing. Usually you'd do something like

```
Blockly.Python["import_block"] = function (block) {
    return "<your code>";
}
```

Have a look at the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/create-custom-blocks/generating-code)!